# In place intersection of two collections of different types

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a collection of Employee objects

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees;
```

where employee looks like this:

```
    class Employee
    {
        int Id {get; set;}
        int Name {get; set;}
    }
```

I have a second collection:

```
IEnumerable<int> fired;
```

I want to do an intersection of employees and fired in place based on the Id property of the Employee. Something like:

```
employees.Intersect(fired)
```

This of course won't work because employee and fired are different types. I know I can do something like this:

```
List<int> empIds = null;
employees.Foreach(x => empIds.Add(x.Id);
```

and then do a intersection of empIds and fired and then merge it back. But there must be a way to do this in place without declaring a new List. My goal is to have a method where you pass in the employees collection by reference and it would 'filter out' the fired employees:

```
void YourRFired(ref IEnumerable<employee> employees)
{
    IEnumerable<int> fired = .....

   // intersect employee and fired here to get a list of employees that are      
    not fired.
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a where?

```
var notFiredEmployees = employees.Where(e=>!fired.Contains(e.Id));
```

Comment: Thanks that would work... I guess in my mind I was too focused on the 'inersect'

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
IEnumerable<Employee> employees;
IEnumerable<int> firedEmployeeIds;

//return all employees who are not fired
return employees
    .GroupJoin(firedEmployeeIds, e => e.Id, f => f, (employee, ids) => new 
    { 
        employee, 
        fired = ids.Any() == false 
    })
    .Where(x => x.fired == false)
    .Select(x => x.employee);
```